# Can not disable spring security with userdetailservice autoconfig?

Tags: spring-security

I have this HTTP config and some restful API to test login and register in the database but it always got "Unauthorized". But I disabled it? Why? pls, help.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().authorities("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you use:
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
Are you using spring-boot?

Comment: I use spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I added this `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })` to main void then the issue resolve.